# Cannot connect to other PC's localhost through intranet

Tags: internet-explorer, intranet

I updated my Internet Explorer from IE7 to IE8. I usually used the IE7 to connect to other PC's localhost in the intranet. But, when the IE is updated to the v8, I couldn't access the other PC's localhost, it keeps asking me for username and password, and no username and password that work. Are there any configurations needed to bypass this ? Thx.

I use the other PC's name or IP address to access it from my PC (http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/**application**), the **application** is developed by using ASP .NET

Comment: This needs much more information, like how you are calling the other PC and what software is running on it

Comment: This is impossible to answer. You need to look into the other PC, what server software it is running, and why it is asking for a password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, you need to make some account changes on IIS or re-install it. Also, please try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and see if it makes any difference (sometimes it does).

Comment: i'm trying to access other's localhost, is it possible to use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` ?

Comment: @Andha no. `localhost` always refers to the own machine

Comment: @Andha: Pekka is right. You should have said "other PC" or "other host" not "other localhost". It's obviously a security permission problem. But if we are talking about other PCs, forget about IIS. It's probably caused by IE's permissions.

Comment: @EmirAkaydın actually that's what i posted "other PC's localhost", but it's okay, skip that one. anyway, how to configure the IE's permissions ?